# Objects getting placed in below the upper canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

during page load , I am adding objects to canvas which are getting added below the upper canvas because of which I am not able to select the objects. Can any one please tell me how this fabric canvas behaves during page load. When add objects after page load , the added objects are selectable but the ones which I have added during page load I am not able to select.

Comment: Wait for `window.onload` so that the DOM has fully initiated the canvas element and any related resources (like images & fonts). Trying to use the canvas before it's fully initiated can result in silent failure of the preload JS code.

Comment: @markE var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', { selection: true }); , this line I have added in $(document).ready(function(){} and I have added all the event handlers in this jquery function itself. But I am calling a function to set back ground image of canvas and after that I called a function to add the shapes to canvas in WINDOW.ONLOAD function.